# Splitting of charge in a symmetry argument

Tags: electromagnetism, thought-experiment

Suppose we have some object that has charge $q$ and we take an identical object and we bring the two objects together. One asks what the charge on either object would be after separating them. According to prof Shankar ([lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NK-BxowMIfg&list=PLB1A0BF14EB31C3BE) @43:47) the objects will split the charge evenly (a symmetry argument).

Question 1. Is it assumed $q = q_e(2k)$ i.e an even multiple of the elementary charge?

Question 2. Does it make sense to consider where one object has precisely $q_e$ charge? If yes, how would the charge split if brought to contact with an identical object and separated?

Question 3. Assuming protons or electrons are 'irreducible', is any charge non-integer multiple of $q_e$ attainable? E.g $\frac{1}{2}q_e, \pi q_e$?

In the same lecture, it is also mentioned that charge is quantized (multiples of $|q_e| \approx 1.6\cdot 10^{-19}\ \mbox{C}$). Hence I think Q3 is answered in the negative, however, I didn't understand which multiples of $q_e$ were meant: rational, integral?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have non-integral multiple of 
as charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439929/206691)

Answer (score 2):

Q1. No, but to claim two charges will be equal is true upto $10^{-19}$ error (if our initial charge was about 1 Coulomb). That is, for everyday charges we can assume with extremely low error that the charge is not quantized.

Q2. Yes, a nice example would be $_1\text{H}^+$ ($q=+q_e$) vs. $_1\text{H}$ ($q=0$). After a collision, either one of the protons will retain the electron. Notice the error here is $10^0$, since our initial charge was 1 $q_e$ to begin with (I guess the second proton gets the $\text{e}^-$ due to conservation of momentum but I'm not sure.).

Q3. Well, the lowest charge among elementary particles (i.e. matter) is $1/3\cdot q_e$ (anti-down and anti-strange quarks, which are always bound in nature). Since every matter is made up from these particles, we always get a charge as an integer multiple of $q_e$ for normal matter, and an integer multiple of $1/3\cdot q_e$ if we are looking at a particle collider data.

*edit: anti-quarks are usually not bound due to matter-antimatter interactions, but their normal counterparts are.

**edit: Down and strange quarks themselves have $-1/3\cdot q_e$ charges. But for heuristic reasons I gave the positive charged antiparticles (sorry about that).

Comment: "anti-quarks are usually not bound..." What about antiprotons?